# RSClientController is undefined

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

What is the cause of this error: "RSClientController is undefined"? It is associated with a ReportViewerWebControl displayed on a ASP.NET page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ReportViewerWebControl needs to be registered through the Handler Mappings in IIS.

Comment: This is obviously an old problem, but I added a Handler Mapping to a site I'm trying to move (not a webdev) and I'm still getting the same error :( any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I have not changed anything in the app pool just added this line:

```
<Add name = "Reserved-ReportViewerWebControl-axd" path = "Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb = "*" type = "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler" resourceType = "Unspecified" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this on a web application project upgraded from VS2012 to VS2015 by selecting the project in Solution Explorer, press F4 and change to Integrated Managed Pipeline Mode.